# Hola, ¿Cómo puedo implementar ".setItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener)"?

Tags: android-studio, android-navigationview

1. Necesito modificar este código para mi `bottonNavigationView`, ya que esta forma está en desuso
2. Estoy aplicando Actividades
3. ¿Cómo le puedo hacer?

```
       nav = findViewById(R.id.Navigation);
        nav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.courses);

        nav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    finish();
                    return true;

                case R.id.courses:
                    return true;

                case R.id.mycourses:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyCoursesActivity.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    finish();
                    return true;

                case R.id.profile:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    finish();
                    return true;

                case R.id.Exit:
                    mAuth.signOut();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    finish();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: Pues yo diría que borrando "OnNavigation" ya lo tendrías. Yo le echaría un ojo a qué es una expresión lambda y un interfaz funcional. Y da la impresión de que todos los case de "tu" código son muy muy parecidos, quizás se pudiera simplificar un poco para que no fuera tan repetitivo

Comment: Hola, gracias por decirme, pero al momento de retirar el "OnNavigation", los "case R.id.N" me aparece que es una expresión no permitida, si eres tan amable, me podrías dar un ejemplo 

Comment: Perdona, creo que solo tienes que borrar "Navigation". Como ya dije no soy experto en Android. El título de tu pregunta me confundió. Según la documentación de Android, debes sustituir BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener por NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener con lo cual supongo que el método correcto es nav.setOnItemSelectedListener. Por favor, edita el título para indicar el método correcto si estoy en lo cierto

Answer (score 0):

Como comentas, el uso de [OnNavigationItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) es obsoleto, ahora se debe usar [NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener](https://%20NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener), el cambio consiste simplemente en cambiar el método usado, ahora de esta forma:

```
//bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
    // do something!

    return true;
});
```

Por lo tanto, el cambio simplemente sería:

```
nav.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.home:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    finish();
                    break;

                case R.id.courses:
                    break;

                case R.id.mycourses:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyCoursesActivity.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    finish();
                    break;

                case R.id.profile:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                    finish();
                    break;

                case R.id.Exit:
                    mAuth.signOut();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        });
```

Se usa un `break` en cada opción y al final siempre se retorna `true`.